# Big Query SQL for finding all products where every sku has a specific status

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got the following table (note a sku is a child of a product - ie if a product is a tshirt, then there might be a different sku for each colour of tshirt)...

```
Product_ID, SKU_ID, Status
1           1       InStock
1           2       SpecialOrder
2           3       SpecialOrder
2           4       SpecialOrder
3           5       InStock
```

..I want to identify those products where all of the skus are status SpecialOrder. ie in the example above only product 2.

I have created an alias (ie using a WITH BLAH AS SELECT...) of this table with only status = "SpecialOrder" and joined it to the main table, which has given me this sort of structure, which I think is half way there, but I just can't figure out how to finish it. Or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree?

```
Product_ID, SKU_ID, Status,       Product_ID, SKU_ID, Status
null,       null,   null          1           1       InStock
1           2       SpecialOrder  1           2       SpecialOrder
2           3       SpecialOrder  2           3       SpecialOrder
2           4       SpecialOrder  2           4       SpecialOrder
null,       null,   null,         3           5       InStock
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  logical_and(Status = 'SpecialOrder') over(partition by Product_ID) as AllSpecialOrder
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case if you want to get out products only - consider below

```
select Product_ID
from your_table
group by Product_ID
having logical_and(Status = 'SpecialOrder')
```

with output

[image]